# How to use setHint() in autocompletetextview programmatically in android

Tags: android

I am using a autocompletetextview in my app.I want to set hint in this by code.Is it possible?

Used Xml code is..

```
   <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autoCompletedTextView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size12sp" />
```

code is........

```
autocompleted.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.select_pickuplocation));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and easy. Try with this...

```
autoCompleteTextView.setHint("Your Hint");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is with **xml**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordEntry"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Test" />
```

Other way is **programatically**

```
autoCompleteTextView1.setHint("YourHint");
```

and if you want to set Text from your `strings` resources you can do it like this:

```
autoCompleteTextView1.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.yourString));
```

Hope to help!

Comment: setText() is working perfectly but setHint not working.

Comment: hmm .. but you want to set it programatically?

Comment: can you post little code because its hard to solve that way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display hint at the bottom of the matching list, use [`setCompletionHint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setCompletionHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). If you want to use normal hint, use [`setHint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).